# BrowserSync inject CSS with version in URL

Tags: node.js, gulp, browser-sync

Take the file `assets/css/main.css`, sprinkle in a RewriteRule, now you can have:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main.X.css" />
```

Trouble is, BrowserSync can no longer "map" the URL to the file, and CSS injection fails. Trawling through the docs has brought nothing to light, wondered if anyone has encountered a similar situation? Typical gulp setup:

```
gulp.task( "sass", function() {
    return gulp.src( "scss/main.scss" )
        .pipe( sass() )
        .pipe( gulp.dest( "assets/css" ) )
        .pipe( browserSync.stream() );
});

gulp.task( "default", [ "sass" ], function() {
    browserSync.init({
        proxy  : "localhost"
    });

    gulp.watch( "scss/**/*.scss", [ "sass" ] );
});
```